# How to Remove Particular Element from Array in Javascript with a button

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, constructor, splice

I want to be able to press on my trashcan and be able to delete any todo i want. Right now i can only remove the first index off my todo with with the help off splice. Also when i inspect my array in console i want to be able to use true or false. So when i click on my button my object gets removed from my screen and inside off the array in console it should show that my object indeed have been removed and turns into true instead of false( todoIsRemoved: false). here is a link so you can see all off my code: https://jsfiddle.net/marvstarv/tqdzn8bg/.

this is my class:

```
let p=0;
let allTheToDos = [];

class Todo{
    constructor(toDoItem, removedToDo){
        this.Id= p ++;
        this.toDoItem = toDoItem;
        this.removedToDo = removedToDo;
    }
}
```

this is the function i need help with,

```
function removeTask (){
    let liContainer = document.getElementById ("mySection"); // contains my label(checkmark), Li, and trashcan button.
    allTheToDos.splice(Todo,1);
    liContainer.innerHTML="";
    generateHtml();
    console.log(allTheToDos);
}
```

this function is conected to line 64 off my "main.js": `deleteButton.addEventListener('click', () =>{removeTask(allTheToDos[i])});`

i appriciate all the help, get back to me if anything was unclear.enter code here

Answer (score 0):

I updated your Js file to:

```
window.onload = function(){
    // without this my site keeps realoding when adding a new item
    let firstTask = new Todo ('Bädda sängen',false);
    let secondTask = new Todo ('Hänga upp tavlorna',false);
    let thirdTask = new Todo ('Kick back & realx',false);

    // Adding my premade todo's into my Array that has the variable 'allTheToDos'
    allTheToDos.push(firstTask);
    allTheToDos.push(secondTask);
    allTheToDos.push(thirdTask);

    // creating a function so that the user can add a new todo
    let addButton = document.getElementById('addBtn');
    addButton.addEventListener('click',addNewTask);

    generateHtml ();

    // let checkedLi = document.getElementById('listItem')
    // checkedLi.addEventListener('click',)

    console.log(allTheToDos);
}
// my puublic 
let p=0;
let allTheToDos = [];

class Todo{
    constructor(toDoItem, removedToDo){
        this.Id= p ++;
        this.toDoItem = toDoItem;
        this.removedToDo = removedToDo;
    }
}



function generateHtml (){
    // Creating an Ul for my items
    let section = document.getElementById('mySection');
    let myUl = document.createElement('ul');
    myUl.className = 'listContainer';
    section.appendChild(myUl);

    // Creating the loop for my premade todo objects
    for(i=0; i<allTheToDos.length; i++){
        // Create a div wrapper for my li
        let myListWrapperItemContainer = document.createElement('div');
        myListWrapperItemContainer.className = "listItemsWrapper";

        let id = `to_do_${i}`;
        myListWrapperItemContainer.id = id;
        // Creating Checked button
        let checkedIcon = document.createElement('label');
        checkedIcon.className = 'checkedIcon listItemsIcon';
        checkedIcon.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>';
        //Creating li
        let myLi = document.createElement("li");
        myLi.classList = "listItem lineTrough";
        myLi.id= "listItem";
        // Creating delete button
        let deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
        deleteButton.id ="deleteButton";
        deleteButton.className = 'trashCan listItemsIcon';
        deleteButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>';
        // OnClick
        deleteButton.addEventListener('click', () => {removeTask(id)});

        // Adding everything to my html
        myListWrapperItemContainer.appendChild(checkedIcon);
        myListWrapperItemContainer.appendChild(myLi);
        myListWrapperItemContainer.appendChild(deleteButton);
        myLi.innerHTML = allTheToDos[i].toDoItem;
        myUl.appendChild(myListWrapperItemContainer);
    }
}

function addNewTask (stopRefresh){
    stopRefresh.preventDefault();
    let liContainer = document.getElementById ("mySection");
    let inputValue = document.getElementById('textBox').value;
    liContainer.innerHTML="";

    if (inputValue == ""){
        alert("Type in something");
        generateHtml();
    }
    else{
        let newInputValue = new Todo (inputValue);
        allTheToDos.push(newInputValue);
        generateHtml();
    }

}
function removeTask (id){
    let element = document.getElementById(id);
    let index = allTheToDos.findIndex(e => e.toDoItem === element.textContent);
    allTheToDos.splice(index,1);
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
```